# Laravel keeps reloading and nothing comes up

Tags: mysql, laravel, apache, xampp

After I type php artisan serve in my terminal, laravel development server start : http://127.0.0.1:8000

But when I do reload in my browser, it keeps loading and doesn't show any error

And again this happens to all my project I have.

I don't know what's going on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this by running this command instead of php artisan serve.

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

Then try to run again in your browser localhost:8000

Hope it helps, happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it with `php artisan config:cache` and then restart your server with `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

you can change laravel port:
php artisan serve --port=8080

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problime and i solved its write: php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 and will show firewall click on allow and will work [note example #6](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your problem some file that crash on your project for that run this commend

```
php artisan config:cache // clear config cache
php artisan config:clear // clear config cache
php artisan cache:clear // clear cache
php artisan optimize  // To reoptimize the class loader
php artisan route:cache // clear route cache
php artisan view:clear // clear view cache
```

or may port 8000 reserved by other program for that use this commend to change port

```
php artisan serve --port=1000
//then type http://127.0.0.1:1000/ on your browser.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, and later only I figured out my **virus guard** is the reason, to figure out I've spend almost a day. if non of the above solution worked for you please check by disabling your **virus guard**

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the element and see if there's any error in console

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: This seems like a decent hint for debugging, but not like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I spent hours trying to solve it. Finally, I installed a new Laravel project (versions 8 & 9) and could not pull it up.

Clear your browser cache. Try another browser and see if it pulls up.

Answer (score -1):

Try http://localhost:8000

You are missing a 0 in the port number.
If that doesn't work, try running 'ping localhost:8000' and post back the results.

Comment: When I run ping localhot:800 it says Ping request could not find host localhost:8000 please check the name and try again.

Comment: And if I run ping 8000 it gives Pinging 0.0.31.64 with 34 bytes of data: ping: transmit failed, General failure. This repeats four time and packets: sent = 4, Receive = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Comment: What, if anything, does your laravel.log file say?